# "User Profile Synchronization Service" missing in SP2016

Tags: user-profile, 2016, synchronization

In SP2016,"User Profile Synchronization Service" missing in "Manage Services in Server".

I already ran Install-SPService but still "User Profile Synchronization Service" is not available.

We are using Enterprise version of SP2016

Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

User Profile Service Application was changed significantly in SharePoint Server 2016. Forefront Identity Manager is no longer used for synchronization and there is no User Profile Synchronization Service. SharePoint Server 2016 uses one directional Active Directory Import which is faster and more reliable.

More info:

http://www.maadarani.com/sharepoint-2016-user-profile-service-microsoft-identity-management/

https://jerryyasir.wordpress.com/tag/sharepoint-2016sp2016-step-by-stepmim/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. We are migrating from SP2013 to SP2016. As part of this migration,User Profile services' "Profile DB" and "Social DB" has been upgraded to SP2016. I created a new "User Profile Service Connection" with "Active Directory Import". Now,when I check the "Manage user property",all the mapped attributes(from SP2013) are broken and I'm not able to create a new mapping as no attribute is displayed to be mapped. Can you help me with this?

Comment: I have facing exactly the same issue like here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/9f5d3d44-40e9-43c9-aca0-67ea9df8a0a8/upgrade-user-profile-service-from-2013-to-2016?forum=SP2016